# Change UIButton class at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

So I have two `UIButton's`, both are connected to class `LikeShape.swift`
[image]

I have another class named `LikeShapeDone.swift` that I want to set at runtime like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostsCollectionViewCell

        if (likedBy[indexPath.row].containsObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)){
                // Post is liked by the current user
                imageCell.likeButton = LikeShape()
                imageCell.dislikeButton = LikeShapeDone()
            }
            if (dislikedBy[indexPath.row].containsObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)){
                // Post is disliked by the current user
                imageCell.dislikeButton = LikeShapeDone()
                imageCell.likeButton = LikeShape()
            }
            else{
                // Post is not liked by the current user
            }
        // <---- End ImageCell Row ---->
        return imageCell
    }
```

But nothing happens.. I am 100% sure that the current user is in `likedBy` and `dislikedBy` The LikeShape class has black button, and LikeShapeDone has red button, but the buttons is only black all the time... Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion : Create one button and change the type at runtime not whole class or whole button.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Do you mean like: `imageCell.likeButton = LikeShape()`? That is what i tried, and did not work.

Comment: create one button LikeDislikeButton.type = like or dislike. change at runtime

Comment: @AshishKakkad - Huh? http://s16.postimg.org/k75zjconp/Screen_Shot_2016_04_14_at_14_22_10.png

Comment: Maybe you should try debugging.  Set a breakpoint on `return imageCell` and examine the value of `imageCell.dislikeButton`.

Comment: @RoduckNickes You are not getting.

Comment: i would recommend to create a method on your "LikeButton" to change the style. So you dont need 2 different classes. And then only do somethink lik LikeButton.setType(1)....

Comment: @derdida that what I want to say. but the Roduck is not getting.

Comment: @derdida How would I do that?

Comment: How you could create a different type? Create a Class function, and set background image / style in this function. And then just call that "setType" function and set the type of button on runtime as you want.

Comment: @derdida Value of type `UIButton` has no member "setType"

Comment: Of yourse. You need to create am method to change the type. I will provide an answer, just gimme one sec

Answer (score 2):

As recommended in my comment, i would create 1 Class for your Button, where are you able to set the type of the button directly in runtime. For example:

```
public class LikeButton: UIButton {

    public func setLike(type: String) {

    switch(type) {

    case "blue":
        self.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    break;

    case "red":
        self.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
        break;

    case "black":
        self.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        break;

    case "white":
        self.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        break;

    default:
    break
    }
}
```

Edit again: This only makes sense if you REALLY need to extend the current UIButton. This makes sense when you have multiple parameters, and you dont want to set them every time to your UIButton Class.

You could (of course) set:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal) //Any Color
```

Usage of Code Top:

```
myLikeButton = LikeButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,50))
myLikeButton.setLike("blue")
```

Or (on runtime)

```
myLikeButton.setLike("red")
```

Comment: Can you add example code where you define 4 different types? To change between color black, white, red and blue?

Comment: Do i create a swift class or Cocoa class?

Comment: Doesent matter. CocoaTouch classes only brings a Boilerplate of Code

Comment: I don't understand why it wont work for me: http://s9.postimg.org/46hpndifj/Screen_Shot_2016_04_14_at_20_40_55.png

Comment: SetValue is an UIButton Class Function - Choose another Name

Comment: I got something like this: http://s28.postimg.org/w7rr52w99/Screen_Shot_2016_04_14_at_21_51_28.png

Comment: Yes, your Parameter for setLike is from value "LikeButton" - thats wrong: use: public func setLike(type: String): But why do you really want to subclass an UIButton? If you only want to change the background Color on runtime, just use myButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)

Comment: Background color was just an example. I want to change the button shape in runtime and the shape is a UIBezierPath.